# почему код выдает ошибку list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python

```
def rand_b():
    col = randint(2,8)
    while True:
        for i in range(col):
            p = randint(2, 2)
            ptr.append(p)
        m1 = ptr.count(1)
        m2 = ptr.count(2)
        shuffle(ptr)
        print(ptr)
        print(col)
        if m2 == col or m1 == col:
            ptr.remove(all)
        else:
            break
rand_b()
```

Comment: Могу предположить, что вам нужно использовать ptr.clear(), а не remove(). А какой вообще результат вы ожидаете получить? Да и условие у вас всегда будет отрабатывать True, цикл будет вечным...непонятное.

Comment: потому что в списке нет встроенной функции ``all``!

Comment: ... но её можно туда положить. И будет список который содержит всё!

Answer (score 0):

[`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) - имя глобальной функции в Питоне:

> ```
> $ python -c "help(all)"
>
> Help on built-in function all in module builtins:
>
> all(iterable, /)
>     Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.
>     
>     If the iterable is empty, return True.
> (END)
> ```

Возможно вы хотели удалить все элементы из списка. Для этого есть `ptr.clear()`.

Comment: Я бы сказал не *глобальной*, а *встроенной*.

Comment: @wchistow, вы правы. Я хотел указать что имя `all` доступно внутри функции потому что оно определено в глобальной области видимости.